# I lost the menu inside of Explorer (file browser) under Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

The question says it all. Inside of the file explorer under Windows XP, I lost all menu items from the top, as well as the toolbars. And right-clicking only gives me the file/directory context menu, nothing to restore the toolbar or the menu. Help. I don't use Windows so much (I much prefer linux), so I don't know all the latest tricks and hacks.

Merci :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following site has several tips to try in order to find the menu bar:

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/117914-45-windows-explorer-toolbar-missing

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Start | Run | Type: gpedit.msc | Click OK | 
Navigate to >>> 
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\ 
Windows Explorer\ 
Find section called "Remove File menu from Windows Explorer" 
Set to: Not configured

Answer (score 0):

From Robert William's answer.  This is what worked for me:

In Full Screen (F11) the Menu Bar, the Address Bar and Links can be added. 
You can also right click the Toolbar and select Menu Bar.